# Matlab typecast transfer to python 3.7

Tags: matlab, python-3.7, uint32

I have some excerpt code for Matlab. I want to transfer to python3.7 code.  But I found out some Matlab function I can not transfer to python 3.7  it, such as function typecast, and single in Matlab.
Therefore, How could I write the python code and get the same result?
Thank you

Here is the Matlab code

```
AA= uint32(3249047552)
DPD = typecast(AA,'single');    
Print(DPD)
```

DPD = -21.0664  <== This is matlab result.

Comment: Convert `AA` to base 2 then use the IEEE Standard 754 for single precision to compute the corresponding single value.

Comment: Please don’t change the question after you’ve received an answer. Your edit made the answer seem wrong. Instead, accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

With `numpy` you can use [`view()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html):

```
# Define your uint32 number
x = np.array(3249047552, dtype=np.uint32)
# Get the equivalent bitwise single number
x.view(np.single)
# output: -21.066406
```